# Match a section in Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I have been breaking my head for a while now but not able to get the regular expression.

I have the plain text as below

```
1.1 Section 

dsfdsf
g
fdgdf
g
dfgfdg

1.2 Section

This is the 
first section

1.3 Section
dfgdfgfd
g
dfgdfg

1.4 Section
dfgfdgfd
g
fdg
```

I want to find all the secions.

**Match 1**

```
1.1 Section 

dsfdsf
g
fdgdf
g
dfgfdg
```

**Match 2**

```
1.2 Section

This is the 
first section
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want your expression to match exactly?

Comment: done some formatting @NickParsons

Comment: You should not (always) use a regex for matching for that kind of text. With a simple logic test you could split by yourself.

Comment: I have simplified the text as an illestration. The actual text is way too complex. @MarkusZeller

Comment: May be something like this.. ^[\d\.]+[\s]*Section(?:(?![Section]{6}).)* I know I am wrong but can someone help me?

Comment: And the regex would be maybe even more complicated. Just scan line by line. Check for section (maybe with or without regex). Now just split positions from 1 section to the next.

Comment: I know it is complex but splitting the actual thing is way too complex I promise. May be I need a solution with some sort fo lookaheads. @MarkusZeller

Comment: No, its simple :D What language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex is what you need,

```
\d+\.\d+\s+Section[\w\W]+?(?=\R*(?:\d+\.\d+|$))
```

Explanation to this regex is following,

- `\d+\.\d+` - Matches one or more digits followed by dot followed by one or more digits.
- `\s+Section` - Matches one or more whitespace followed by `Section` word. You can enable `i` flag if you want to make it case insensitive.
- `[\w\W]+?(?=\R*(?:\d+\.\d+|$))` - Captures one or more any characters including newlines as less as possible due to non-greedy (`+?`) capture and stops just before either when it sees an optional new line followed by one or more digits plus a dot followed by one or more digits or end of string.

[Demo url](https://regex101.com/r/CLzSfI/1/)